# Return file as byte array in Spring Cloud Function on AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

How can I return a pdf file using Spring Boot Cloud function?
I'm using this code

```
return new GenericMessage(
                    documentBytes,
                    Map.of(
                            "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream",
                            "statuscode", HttpStatus.OK.value(),
                            "Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=%s", inputRequestData.getDocumentFileName())
                    )
            );
```

But it doesn't work (also tried with "Content-Type", "application/pdf").
Thank you

Comment: What happens? This line returns to where?